# How to convert data type from Cil_types to Cil

Tags: ocaml, static-code-analysis, frama-c

When I use fram-c to write parser. I encountered a problem that Ast.get() returns the type Cil_types.file but I need Cil.file for future use. They are actually has the same fields, but the ocaml compiler just not let the direct assignment from Cil_types.file to Cil.file. 
Is there any type cast functions in Ocaml can help me do this.

Ps:
I try to assign each field of Cil_types.file to Cil.file, but the same problem happens recursively (do not allow Cil.file.* = Cil_types.file.*). 
I really appreciate your help！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Frama-C`, there is no `Cil_types.file` type. Maybe you are mixing `Frama-C` with the original `Cil`?

Comment: Hi, originally, I also think that Cil_types.file and Cil.file should not be used in the same file. 
However, the function Ast.get() will return a Cil_type.file() which defined in [frama-c-Nitrogen-20111001/src/kernel/ast.ml](http://docs.camlcity.org/docs/godisrc/frama-c-Nitrogen-20111001.tar.gz/frama-c-Nitrogen-20111001/src/kernel/ast.ml)
And the function computeGraph() will need a Cil.file as the input.
What can I do to do the transformation of the two actually the same data type?

Comment: Actually, why I encountered this problem is that, I am currently modifying a project written in Frama-c-Lithium_20081201 version.   
It uses computeGraph(Cil_state.file).   However In the next release of Frama-c, it changes Cil_state to Ast and Cil_state.file to Ast.get(). which changes the return type to Cil_types.file. I don't know how to fill the gap :(

Comment: Maybe you can try running the scripts in bin/ in the order of atomic elements, that does a large part of the conversion. The script lithium2beryllium seems to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but how can I find lithium2beryllium, I didn't find it in the frama-c folder?

Comment: It is in the bin folder of the Frama-C distribution.